Unable to input and output properly when programming a Knapsack problem
I am trying to solve a Knapsack problem with a two-dimensional array on CodeBlocks, but after the program runs, I press the number on the keyboard, and the running terminal does not display the number I pressed. (Does this mean I did not input successfully?) I press the number on the keyboard a few more times, and the program exits without outputting. Why is this?
Here is my code
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int c,n,v;
int main()
{
    cin >> c;
    while(c--){
        cin >> n >>v;
        int dp[1005][1005] = {0};
        int val[1005];
        int cap[1005];
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        //a[1005][1005] = {0};
        for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
            cin >> val[i];
        for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
            cin >> cap[i];
        //ll maxv = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++ ){
            for (int j = 1;j<=v;j++){
                if(j>=cap[i]){
                    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j],dp[i-1][j - cap[i]]+val[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << dp[n][v] << endl;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

Here is the Knapsack problem I am tring to solve.
Bone Collector
Problem Description:
Many years ago , in Teddy’s hometown there was a man who was called “Bone Collector”. This man like to collect varies of bones , such as dog’s , cow’s , also he went to the grave …
The bone collector had a big bag with a volume of V ,and along his trip of collecting there are a lot of bones , obviously , different bone has different value and different volume, now given the each bone’s value along his trip , can you calculate out the maximum of the total value the bone collector can get ?
Input：
The first line contain a integer C , the number of cases.
Followed by C cases , each case three lines , the first line contain two integer N , V, (N <= 1000 , V <= 1000 )representing the number of bones and the volume of his bag. And the second line contain N integers representing the value of each bone. The third line contain N integers representing the volume of each bone.
Output：
One integer per line representing the maximum of the total value (this number will be less than 231).
Sample Input:
1
5 10
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
Sample Output:
14
I tried add an output before entering c to see whether the input part works properly,like this:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//typedef long long ll;
int c,n,v;
int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter c." <<endl;
    cin >> c;
    while(c--){
        cin >> n >>v;
        int dp[1005][1005] = {0};
        int val[1005];
        int cap[1005];
        memset(dp,0,sizeof(dp));
        //a[1005][1005] = {0};
        for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
            cin >> val[i];
        for (int i = 1;i <= n;i++)
            cin >> cap[i];
        //ll maxv = 0;
        for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++ ){
            for (int j = 1;j<=v;j++){
                if(j>=cap[i]){
                    dp[i][j] = max(dp[i - 1][j],dp[i-1][j - cap[i]]+val[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        cout << dp[n][v] << endl;
    }
    return 0 ;
}

However,there is no output "Please enter c." and I cannot enter numbers.

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

Unrelated: I see a lot of bad programming habits in the code. For example, unnecessary use of global variables. Use of #include <bits/stdc++.h> etc. More importantnly, lack of use of a debugger. Note that reading documentation and using a debugger is important part of programming. So what is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems should help.

I suspect dp is large enough (~4 MB) to make your program crash with a stack overflow before it gets anywhere. Make it global.

I recommend you stop competitive coding using C++ for now and first spent some time on learning C++ itself (it will avoid a lot of frustration later). E.g. have a look at learncpp.com.  int dp[1005][1005] = {0}; is just setting yourself up for memory issues, use something like std::vector<std::vector<int>> (@molbdnilo I do not agree with teaching people to use global variables).  If you're only into competitive coding for your problem solving skills switch to Python. (Just don't use C++ because you heared its faster)

int dp[1005][1005] int val[1005]; -- This is another bad habit that persons using competitive coding websites that do not learn C++ make.  That habit is declaring gigantic arrays, just because the constraints to the question say "up to 1005".  Just because the number of input can be up to 1005 doesn't mean you blindly declare arrays of 1005 in size.  What if the input data only has 10 items?  You would have wasted 995 elements that do nothing.  Instead of declaring gigantic arrays, use an empty std::vector and push_back the items that are read in.
